# Redirecting updated request does not show

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to pass updated request (req.update), adding an object to it, but when redirecting from one route ('/') to another ('/dashboard') it does not hold the updates on the (req.update).

```
router.post('/signin' , myAuth, signIn);
function signIn (req , res , next){
  console.log(req.userId, 'woooooooooooooorked');
  // router.get('/dashboard');
  res.redirect(303 ,'/dashboard');
  // next(res.redirect('/dashboard'));
}
```

```
router.get('/dashboard' , dashboard) ;

async function dashboard(req ,res ,next){
  console.log(req.userId , '*********');

  let scanResult = await Model.get(req._id);
  console.log(scanResult , 'dashboard');
  res.status(200).send(scanResult);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `res.redirect` it will send a response to the client with `redirect` headers and then the client will initiate a new request, so all previous data will be lost at this time.

You could use `app.set()` method to set the data and get it in other routes.

**Example.**

```
router.post('/signin' , myAuth, signIn);
function signIn (req , res , next){
  app.set('userId', req.userId);
  console.log(req.userId, 'woooooooooooooorked');
  res.redirect(303 ,'/dashboard');
}
```

```
router.get('/dashboard' , dashboard) ;

async function dashboard(req ,res ,next){
  console.log(req.userId , '*********');

  let scanResult = await Model.get(app.get('userId'));
  console.log(scanResult , 'dashboard');
  res.status(200).send(scanResult);
}
```

Or you could use `query strings` to pass the data.

**Example:**

```
router.post('/signin' , myAuth, signIn);
function signIn (req , res , next){
  console.log(req.userId, 'woooooooooooooorked');
  res.redirect(303 ,'/dashboard?userId=' + req.userId);
}
```

```
router.get('/dashboard' , dashboard) ;

async function dashboard(req ,res ,next){
  console.log(req.userId , '*********');

  let scanResult = await Model.get(req.query.userId);
  console.log(scanResult , 'dashboard');
  res.status(200).send(scanResult);
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer , what i want is to pass the same request object of /signin route to the next route which is in this case /dashboard  . ..

Comment: Then you can save the request object in `app.set(req)`. and get it in the dashboard route. 

As I mentioned in my answer the redirect will send response to the client and then the client will create a new request.

Comment: the app.set method dosnt work , the query did , but still not what am looking for :(

Comment: What other information you want to sent other then userID ?

Comment: i wan't to go from route to another passing data with the request object , could i reach that ?

Comment: You could also give the `dashboard ` as the middleware function in signup route. like this. `router.post('/signin' , myAuth, signIn, dashboard)`. and don't send response in signin method and pass the request to the next middleware, but with this the browser url b will not change to dashboard.

Comment: i think of that also , the problem that i need to pass the id of user data in the mongodb through all the routes , for example when i go to the dashboard route i want to go to any route with the ability to use that id ,I may think about using session express, but I'm not sure if this will solve the problem or not! any advice?

Comment: Yes, you could use session for this or could use cookie for this as well. But I would suggest to use some token authentication, like JWT.

Comment: Passing Id to one route like this is fine but share with the whole application is not safer.